Jetpack Compose - Opening camera softlocks the refresh rate to 60hz
I'm building an Android app for scanning barcodes and I have a very esoteric problem regarding the CameraX library's camera.
Every time I open the camera's PreviewView in the app the screen refresh rate falls from my 90hz down to 60hz, which is the expected behavior.
My problem is that every time I close down the composable with the camera the refresh rate stays at 60hz.
Below is a snippet of the code from that camera composable.
val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current
val context = LocalContext.current

val cameraController = remember {
    LifecycleCameraController(context)
}
AndroidView(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    factory = {
        PreviewView(context).apply {
            setBackgroundColor(android.graphics.Color.BLACK)
            scaleType = PreviewView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER
        }.also { previewView ->
            cameraController.bindToLifecycle(lifecycleOwner)
            cameraController.cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA
            previewView.controller = cameraController
        }
    }
)

Doesn't matter if I navigate to a different screen afterwards. The only actions I've noticed put it back to 90hz are: any other system interactions (like pulling down the status bar, leaving the app, opening any other app/system window) and opening the keyboard on any inputs.
Tried a lot of things including lowering compose, camera and navigation libaries' versions and I'm out of ideas. Any idea what could be causing it and how I could fix it? Below is a snippet of the code from that camera composable.

sounds like a bug, create a minimal reproducible example and report it to google issue tracker
